# Simple JSON Serialization with Swift 2.0

Tags: json, swift

I need very simple JSON to Object or JSON to Dictionary conversion within my Swift code. Here is my code to test my serialisation:

```
    let data = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
    let dataData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataData!, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String:String!]
        print(json?["foo"])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Unable to parse json, \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

This code produces:

```
Optional(foo)
```

What do I need to do to get rid of `Optional(foo)` and just get:

```
foo
```

Comment: You need to study [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330). It's a very important Swift feature.

Comment: Thank you, will check it out straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that "foo" is not defined and returns nil. So thats why it is stored as optional. You need to unwrap the variable `foo`. Safe way to do it:

```
if let foo = json?["foo"] {
  print(foo)
}
```